# How to restrict xtightvncserver to listen only to localhost connections?

Tags: 16.04, localhost, tightvncserver

I have installed xtightvncserver on a Ubuntu 16.04 server. I only want to listen to connections from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you amend [iptables](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) to block all port 5901 traffic except from localhost, e.g.:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth1 -s ! localhost --dport 5901 -j DROP   
/sbin/service iptables save
```